# Jenkins groovy pipeline: specifying Java Options

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, ant

We have a relatively simple job configuration which I am trying to convert into a groovy pipeline in Jenkinsfile.

In our classic view, the part "Call Ant" looks like this:
[image]

Now, I am able to specify all those values in the relevant part of the Jenkinsfile, except for Java Options. This is what I am trying:

```
...    
script {
    antTarget = 'configure clean version.file compile jars create.webstart.module.eu.app-main.gui create.war.module.eu.app-main.srv release'
    labelArgument = "-Dlabel=${CURRENT_BUILD}@${GIT_HASH}"
    javaOptions = "-Donline=t"
                
    withAnt(installation: 'Ant Installation', jdk: 'java-for-sonarcube') {
        dir ("ingest/dev") {
            sh "ant ${labelArgument} ${javaOptions} ${antTarget}"
        }
    }
}
...
```

The label gets applied successfully to the build, however regarding the Java Options, obviously I am missing something:

> `/tmp/workspace/nb-ingest_feature_NBINGEST-124/ingest/dev@tmp/durable-fee91921/script.sh: line 2: -Donline=t: command not found`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing a similar kind of issue.This was the solution to it.

```
script{
antTarget = 'cleanlib clean ensure-all-jars jar backport test slowtest cvrgreport-all ivy.publish-hudson'
buildFile = "${WORKSPACE}/java/Utils6/auto_build.xml"
javaOptions = "-Djava.io.tmpdir=${WORKSPACE}/tmp"
prop = "-Divylib=${WORKSPACE}/buildutils/ivy/lib  -Dresolver=hudson-server"
r=params.SVN_BUILD_REVISION
b=params.SVN_BRANCH
rev = "-DSVN_BUILD_REVISION=${r}"
bch = "-DSVN_BRANCH=${b}"                   

withAnt(installation: 'Ant1.9.4', jdk: 'JDK7') {
    sh "ant ${rev} ${bch} ${javaOptions} ${prop} ${antTarget} -file ${buildFile}"
}
```